# Installation failed (IP address blacklisted)

Tags: system-installation, blacklist

**Intro:**

I've got a problem: On many sites that are not located in my country, I must fill in a  CAPTCHA from CloudFlare to access website. Doesn't matter what device: Mobile phone, tablet, laptop, PC... Everywhere.
My computer is not infected, reinstalled OS, checked packets with `wireshark`...

**Problem:**

Installing Ubuntu 14.10 or 14.04 was fine before. Now I cannot install Ubuntu, because packages are not downloaded or missing, cannot update/upgrade Ubuntu after the installation completes and if it completes then it is so laggy, slowly like missing drivers, cannot even load USB flash drive. I'm sure it has something to do with blacklisted ip address in cloudflare.

BTW, I have not public ip address. ISP is using maybe NAT to provide one ip address between many and many other people. So maybe (I'm sure) it is not my fault, but I am very limited now. :(

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* because loading a USB flash drive has nothing to do with IP connectivity.

Comment: Checked packages with wireshark? That's a new one for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was meant: Checked packets with wireshark. My bad.

Comment: The problem is that after visiting sites I got warning message from cloudflare and must write cpatcha code to access website. I thought that cloudflare is blocking me from downloading packages into ubuntu. Never had any problem with installation until now.

Comment: Okay, I'm very sorry for panic, but it seems that it was a problem with GPT partition table. :)